# determinar la posicion de un caracter en un string

Tags: php, string

hola mi pregunta es como puedo determinar la posición del signo de interrogación en este string* para después separarlo con la función `substr()`

```
string = [Catálogo en línea?http://ur_prueba/index.jsp ]
```

Comment: *para después separarlo con la función substr*  ¿significa que quieres hacer dos cadenas, una que contenga `[Catálogo en línea` y la otra: `http://palacioba.ddns.net:8081/palacio/soe/intranet/pieza3/index.jsp ]`? Si es así, puedes hacerlo mediante `explode`. Por ejemplo: `$arr=explode("?",$str); echo $arr[0]; echo $arr[1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que lo más apropiado sería usando [explode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) , usando "?" como delimitar entre los 2 string, de esta forma obtienes un array conteniendo ambas partes:

```
  $string = "[Catálogo en línea?http://ur_prueba/index.jsp ]";      
  $arr=explode("?",$string);
```

de esta forma:

- `$arr[0]` contendría el valor: `"[Catálogo en línea"`
- `$arr[1]` contendría el valor: `"http://ur_prueba/index.jsp ]"`

---

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
    $string = "[Catálogo en línea?http://ur_prueba/index.jsp ]";      
     $arr=explode("?",$string); 
     echo 'Primera parte: '. $arr[0] . '<br>Segunda parte: '. $arr[1]  
?>
```

Para obtener como salida:

```
Primera parte: [Catálogo en línea
Segunda parte: http://ur_prueba/index.jsp]
```

Answer (score 3):

Tenés varias opciones:

```
<?php
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Nótese el uso de ===. Puesto que == simple no funcionará como se espera
// porque la posición de 'a' está en el 1° (primer) caracter.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "La cadena '$findme' no fue encontrada en la cadena '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "La cadena '$findme' fue encontrada en la cadena '$mystring'";
    echo " y existe en la posición $pos";
}
?>
```

Opcion 2:

```
<?php
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// El operador !== también puede ser usado. Puesto que != no funcionará como se espera
// porque la posición de 'a' es 0. La declaración (0 != false) se evalúa a 
// false.
if ($pos !== false) {
     echo "La cadena '$findme' fue encontrada en la cadena '$mystring'";
         echo " y existe en la posición $pos";
} else {
     echo "La cadena '$findme' no fue encontrada en la cadena '$mystring'";
}
?>
```

Para más información chequea la documentación de PHP:

[Documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php)

Para mi es una de las mejores en cuanto a lenguajes

Answer (score 2):

Con la funcion "strpos" puedes obtener la posición donde esta el caracter que estas buscando, supongo que quieres extraer la url, tambien tendrias que quitarle el parentesis cuadrado al final, y el condigo quedaria de esta manera

```
$string = "[Catálogo en línea?http://ur_prueba/index.jsp]"; 
$posicion = strpos ( $string, '?' );
$tamTotal = strlen($string);
echo substr($string,$posicion+1,$tamTotal-$posicion-2);
```

Comment: ok otra pregunta y si el string viene de un query de una base de datos es lo mismo ?